# WCF service is running at computername.mydomain.local/service.svc, why?

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-3.0

My WCF service running on IIS7 seems to resolve at:

http://computername.mydomain.local/service.svc

My web.config doesn't reference any url.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

its because it obtains the name of your computer, you can change it through IIS configuration, also in the WSDL files this references are added

here a [post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1096811/1659596.aspx) for the solution